# Microsoft.Xrm.sdk and Sharepoint 2013 workflow

Tags: workflow

I have written a custom code activity for a SharePoint 2013 workflow that updates CRM 2013.

When the workflow runs, it stops with the status of cancelled and has the message -

"Could not load file or assembly "Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=********" or one of its dependencies."

I have tried copying over the dll's to the bin folder for the Workflow Manager and registering them in the GAC, but doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have solved this issue but now have message - "value cannot be null. parameter name g at system.guid..ctor(string g)"

Answer (score 0):

It now seems to be working after pretty much a full redeploy, so I think registering the two CRM dll's to the GAC was the answer